# How to handle mobile numbers of different countries?

Tags: android, call, blocking

I am building an android app for blocking calls. Now when i am asking the user for contact that he/she wants to block then that number may or may not contain that country's code, while when i will receive a call from that person it will surely have the country code. For example,
in India one can store its number in three different ways:
1) 90331xxxxx
2) 090331xxxxx
3) +9190331xxxxx

Now if user added a contact number which was stored in first way then how could i compare it with the incoming number because the incoming number will be surely having country code.
Also the length of all mobiles number across the world is different. So, how should i compare this numbers.

Comment: You may be able to build a dictionary of sorts, with country codes and their related telephone area codes. You could then check your locale to get the possible area codes and check your phone number against those possible area codes. Just an option, and I am the first to admit it seems like a tedious one.

Comment: Thinking about it some more may also consider breaking the number down into pieces so that you know what the primary 7 digit number is leaving you with the area code at the front, and then (using a similar dictionary idea) check against the matched area codes for that region (so you aren't locale restricted).

Comment: Your idea is absolutely true if we consider for just one country however, different companoes have differnet formats!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/. This has lot of features that you need.

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/#Quick_Examples states how you can use this library to parse numbers and get country specific number, so basically you need to just get the local number using this library and then use that for your comparison.

```
String swissNumberStr = "044 668 18 00"
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
try {
  PhoneNumber swissNumberProto = phoneUtil.parse(swissNumberStr, "CH");
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
  System.err.println("NumberParseException was thrown: " + e.toString());
}

boolean isValid = phoneUtil.isValidNumber(swissNumberProto); // returns true

// Produces "+41 44 668 18 00"
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.INTERNATIONAL));
// Produces "044 668 18 00"
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.NATIONAL));
// Produces "+41446681800"
System.out.println(phoneUtil.format(swissNumberProto, PhoneNumberFormat.E164));
```

Comment: in the example, we know to put "CH" before hand? but how to handle it random phone numbers